# javascript for highlight row and toggle onclick color

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, row, onmouseover

I need to be able do the following on a TR:

- onmouseover highlight the whole row one colour
- onclick the row highlight the row another colour (if you click the same row again it unhighlights the row - sets it to the original bgcolor)
- a problem I have is that in my listview the row's bgcolor alternates between two colours.
- the code below only works for highlighting one row at a time, the row needs to remain highlighted until it is clicked again.

Here is some code that I use for clicking to select which works but I need to change it so that it toggles the row highlight on/off

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var preEl;
var orgBColor;
var orgTColor;
function highlighttr(el, backColor, textColor) {
    if (typeof (preEl) != 'undefined') {
        preEl.bgColor = orgBColor;
        try { ChangeTextColor(preEl, orgTColor); } catch (e) { ; }
    }
    orgBColor = el.bgColor;
    orgTColor = el.style.color;
    el.bgColor = backColor;

    try { ChangeTextColor(el, textColor); } catch (e) { ; }
    preEl = el;
}


function ChangeTextColor(a_obj, a_color) {
    ;
    for (i = 0; i < a_obj.cells.length; i++)
        a_obj.cells(i).style.color = a_color;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Question: Does the state after "clicked" have to stay that way or is it okay if it is only persisted as long as the mouse button is held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a traditional way which by the way is cross-browser (and platform).

CSS

```
.tr {background-color:#fff}
.trOver {background-color:#ddd}
.trClicked {background-color:#bbb}
```

JS

```
function over(o)
{
    if ('trClicked' != o.className) o.className = 'trOver';
}
function out(o)
{
    if ('trClicked' != o.className) o.className = 'tr';
}
function clicked(o)
{
    o.className = ('trClicked' == o.className) ? 'tr' : 'trClicked';
}
```

HTML

```
<tr class="tr" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="clicked(this)">
    // tds without defined background color...
</tr>
```

Comment: just tried that. I'm not getting anything. I have the CSS in the <style> and the JS in a <script type="text/javascript"> of the aspx page. maybe syntax error?

Comment: Sorry. TR with class! <tr class="tr" onmouseover="over(this)"... Corrected also in my answer.

Comment: The onmouseover and onmouseout actually do work. just nothing happens onclick. Wouldnt the onmouseout always overwrite the onclick?

Comment: In my LayoutTemplate of the listview there is this:  <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
            style="table-layout:fixed;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <tr id="headerRow" runat="server" bgcolor="#595959"> Does that make a difference? Shouldnt, thats just for the header

Comment: Sometimes I'm !@#! :( Rename function click to clicked and change onclick="click(this)" to onclick="clicked(this)". Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

- onmouseover highlight the whole row one colour

add `:hover` to `tr` styles

- onclick the row highlight the row another colour (if you click the same row again it unhighlights the row - sets it to the original
  bgcolor)

  ```
  $('tr').click( function () {
      if($(this).hasClass("clicked"))
      {
          $(this).removeClass("clicked");
      }else{
          $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
  });
  ```

and add styles to it.

- a problem I have is that in my listview the row's bgcolor alternates between two colours.

you can add `:nth-child(2n)` to your styles to get it all together.

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/uuZdB/6/

Comment: is the code above jquery? how to formulate so that asp recognizes it? <script type="text/javascript"> code here </style>? and what do you mean add styles to it?

Comment: I wonder why no one else mentioned `tr:hover`. Throwing more Javascript on top of everything is pretty crazy.

Comment: Yes it use jquery but you can also make it without it. Javascript part must be in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag. Styles must be in your style sheep. When i told add styles I mean  that you should add `background-color` to styles rule which use pseudoclasses.

Comment: Just did :) One last thing how to change it so that it caters for alternating rows which have a different colour? As in AlternatingItemTemplate rows will have one colour and ItemTemplate rows will have another colour?